# How to axis-align concatenated images with ImageMagick's montage command?

Tags: imagemagick

I have this image:

[image]

And I want to tile the image so that the result looks like this:

[image]

I need this to be performed for a time-sequence of images, and there are a lot of them, so I want to script the procedure. I have tried `convert +append` and `montage` but I can't seem to get the result.

The command

```
montage -tile 2x -geometry 800x800 lent-scaled.png  lent-scaled.png  lent-scaled.png  result.png
```

results with:

[image]

Is it possible to have this kind of axis-aligned tiling with ImageMagick at all? I didn't find any such hints in the [Montage documentation.](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/)

Comment: Yes its possible generate a empty block of black combine then combine the upper and lower images.

Comment: @joojaa that was my thought as well; I think you should post that as an answer.